# Как проверить, что элемент имеет нужный класс?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Например, есть элемент `p`, который, возможно, имеет класс `SomeClass`.

```
<p class="SomeClass">Текст</p>
```

Как убедиться, что он его действительно имеет из JavaScript или JQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используя *JQuery* можно сделать так:

```
var p = $("p");

if (p.hasClass("SomeClass")) {
    p.text("Класс есть!");
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Решение на чистом JS.

### Вариант 1:

```
elem.className.split(" ").indexOf("класс") !== -1; // true, если класс найден и false, если нет
```

Вместо сравнения с `-1` можно воспользоваться побитовым оператором `~` (тильда):

```
~elem.className.split(" ").indexOf("класс"); // true, если класс найден и false, если нет
```

### Вариант 2:

С псевдомассивом `classList` все куда проще: он имеет встроенный метод `.contains("класс")`, который возвращает `true`, если класс найден и `false`, если нет:

```
elem.classList.contains("класс");
```

Comment: зачем ты пытаешься эмулировать метод [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) из classList? :-) он уже есть, не надо делать slice, indexOf и т.д.

Comment: @Grundy да,  потом увидел это. Уже обновил ответ ведь. Пожалуй, уберу костыль.

Comment: Стоит убрать изыскания с slice и indexOf для classList

Comment: @Grundy вы правы, однозначно. Я и сам так подумал сразу, но не захотел удалять. Теперь поправил.

Answer (score 1):

Или так (тоже c JQuery):

```
var ClassExists = p.is(".SomeClass");
```